# Question About 3-Dimensional Integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble with determining the volume of this solid.

$V := {(x,y,z) : 0 \le x \le 1, x^2 \le y \le \sqrt{x}, -x^{1/3} - y^{1/3} \leq z \leq x^{1/3} + y^{1/3}}$

I started off thinking $\mathrm{vol}(V) \leq \int_0^1 \int_{x^2}^{\sqrt{x}} x^{1/3} + y^{1/3} dy dx$ but I evaluated that integral to be $0$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That integral cannot be $0$ -- your integrand is non-negative, and so the integral being $0$ would imply that either the integrand is always 0 or the region you're integrating over has 0 area.

It is also the case that you're integrand is not *quite* right. Close, though!

This is a straight forward triple integral problem: if $V$ is the region in question, then
$$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Vol}{Vol}\Vol(V)=\iiint_V1\,dV=\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^{\sqrt{x}}\int_{-x^{1/3}-y^{1/3}}^{x^{1/3}+y^{1/3}}1\,dz\,dy\,dx=\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^{\sqrt{x}}2(x^{1/3}+y^{1/3})\,dy\,dx.
$$
For the inner integral, you now get
$$
\int_{x^2}^{\sqrt{x}}2(x^{1/3}+y^{1/3})\,dy=\left.2x^{1/3}y+2\cdot\frac{3}{4}y^{4/3}\right\vert_{y=x^2}^{\sqrt{x}}=2x^{1/3}(\sqrt{x}-x^2)+\frac{3}{2}(x^{2/3}-x^{8/3}).
$$
Then, it is a  matter of integrating this last expression for $x\in[0,1]$.